# 3 Types of Inheritance in JS & The differences in [.isPrototypeOf()] result

Tags: javascript

I believe that there are more than three ways to implement "Inheritance" in Javascript OOP.

Maybe I wrote these codes wrong, but the result of my code is operated in different ways.

(The env is V8)

---

```
   /**
     * Type 1 : "new" Keyword
    */

    //Parent
    function newParent(a,b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    newParent.prototype = {
        print : function() {
            return this.a + '/' + this.b
        }
    }

    //Child
    function newChild(a,b,c) {
        newParent.call(this,a,b);
        this.c = c;
        this.callC = function(){
            return this.c;
        }
    }

    newChild.prototype = new newParent();

    var O = new newChild(1,2,3);
    console.log(O instanceof newChild); //true
    console.log(O instanceof newParent); //true
```

the `new` keyword in `newChild.prototype = new newParent();`.

---

```
/**
 * Type 2 : "Object.create()" 
*/

//Parent
function ocParent(a,b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
ocParent.prototype = {
    print : function() {
        return this.a + '/' + this.b
    }
}

//Child
function ocChild(a,b,c) {
    ocParent.call(this,a,b);
    this.c = c;
    this.callC = function(){
        return this.c;
    }
}

ocChild.prototype = Object.create(ocParent.prototype);
ocChild.prototype.constructor = ocChild;

var OO = new ocChild(1,2,3);
console.log(OO instanceof ocChild); //true
console.log(OO instanceof ocParent); //true
```

The `Object.create()` method in the `ocChild.prototype = Object.create(ocParent.prototype);`.
Also, I connect the *broken* `.constructor` to the `ocChild`.

---

And the last is the latest(?) form.

```
/**
 * Type 3 : Class-extends Keyword
*/
class PParent {
    constructor(a,b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    get print() { //For call this method, Just use '<instance>.print' only.
        return this.a + '/' + this.b;
    }
}

class CChild extends PParent {
    constructor(a,b,c) {
        super(a,b);
        this.c = c;
    }
    get callC() { //For call this method, Just use '<instance>.callC' only.
        return this.c;
    }
}

var OOO = new CChild(1,2,3);
console.log(OOO instanceof CChild); //true
console.log(OOO instanceof PParent); //true
```

---

All `<instance_name> instanceof <constructor_name>` return `true`.
But the `.isprototypeOf()` result of  `O`, `OO`, `OOO` is like this.

```
PParent.isPrototypeOf(CChild)
> true
newParent.isPrototypeOf(newChild)
> false
ocParent.isPrototypeOf(ocChild);
> false
```

Why these results are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your first two methods don't initialize the static prototype chain that `class` syntax does:

```js
/**
 * Type 1 : "new" Keyword
 */

//Parent
function NewParent(a, b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}
NewParent.prototype = {
  print: function() {
    return this.a + '/' + this.b
  }
}

//Child
function NewChild(a, b, c) {
  NewParent.call(this, a, b);
  this.c = c;
  this.callC = function() {
    return this.c;
  }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(NewChild, NewParent); // this line!
NewChild.prototype = new NewParent();

var O = new NewChild(1, 2, 3);
console.log(O instanceof NewChild); //true
console.log(O instanceof NewParent); //true
console.log(NewParent.isPrototypeOf(NewChild)); //true
```

```js
/**
 * Type 2 : "Object.create()" 
 */

//Parent
function OcParent(a,b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
OcParent.prototype = {
    print : function() {
        return this.a + '/' + this.b
    }
}

//Child
function OcChild(a,b,c) {
    OcParent.call(this,a,b);
    this.c = c;
    this.callC = function(){
        return this.c;
    }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(OcChild, Object.create(OcParent)); // this line!
OcChild.prototype = Object.create(OcParent.prototype);
OcChild.prototype.constructor = OcChild;

var OO = new OcChild(1,2,3);
console.log(OO instanceof OcChild); //true
console.log(OO instanceof OcParent); //true
console.log(OcParent.isPrototypeOf(OcChild)); //true
```

I'm not claiming that either of these are identical to how `class` syntax works, just that they now initialize the static prototype chain in a way that's confirmed with [`isPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf).